# Is it possible to improve on this lower bound for $I(n)$, if $\sigma(n^2)=q^k n$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ denote the classical *sum of divisors*.  Denote the *abundancy index* by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

An odd perfect number $N$ is said to be given in *Eulerian form* if
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

The question is as in the title:

> Is it possible to improve on $I(n) > \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}$, if $\sigma(n^2)=q^k n$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

This [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2967348) contains a proof for the inequality
$$I(n) > \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}.$$

So now suppose that $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, and that $\sigma(n^2) = q^k n$.  It follows that
$$I(n^2) = \dfrac{q^k}{n}.$$

This implies that
$$\sigma(q^k) = 2n$$
$$3 > \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} > 2 + \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} \approx 2.722202786849141.$$

I now refer you to the following [publication](https://www.mililink.com/upload/article/1245049093janta_63_dec_2016_pp_95-114_4150301_jose_arnaldo_b._dris.pdf), where it is proved (on pages 106 to 107) that
$$I(q^k) + I(n) \leq \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
holds in general, and further on page 104 that
$$I(q^k) + I(n) \geq \frac{6}{5} + \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} \approx 2.644405573698282.$$

**MY SECOND ATTEMPT**

Since
$$I(n^2) = \dfrac{q^k}{n} \iff \sigma(q^k) = 2n,$$
then we obtain (per this [answer to a closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099121/28816))
$$3 > \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} = \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \dfrac{\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n}}{\dfrac{q^k}{n}} = \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \dfrac{I(n)}{I(n^2)} \geq \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \prod_{p}{\dfrac{p^2 + p}{p^2 + p + 1}} = 2 + \dfrac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)} \approx 2.730762969401438498726,$$
which is *even higher* than the previous lower bound obtained for
$$\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$

*Hence, I am led to believe that it may in fact be possible to improve on the lower bound for $I(n)$.  Alas, this is where I get stuck.*