# Is it possible to prove $I(m^2) > \zeta(2) \approx 1.644934$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$?

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ denote the classical *sum of divisors*.  Denote the *abundancy index* by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

An odd perfect number $N$ is said to be given in *Eulerian form* if
$$N = p^k m^2$$
where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

The question is as in the title:

> Is it possible to prove $I(m^2) > \zeta(2) \approx 1.644934$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

By basic considerations, since $p$ is the special prime and satisfies $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $p \geq 5$ holds, from which it follows that
$$I(p^k)=\dfrac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k}=\dfrac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k (p-1)}<\dfrac{p^{k+1}}{p^k (p-1)}=\dfrac{p}{p-1} \leq \frac{5}{4} \iff I(m^2)=\frac{2}{I(p^k)}>\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p} \geq \frac{8}{5}.$$

Now, I was thinking of attempting to improve this *trivial lower bound* to
$$I(m^2) > \zeta(2) \approx 1.644934.$$

But I know that
$$\zeta(2) = \prod_{\rho}{\bigg({\rho}^2 + {\rho} + 1\bigg)},$$
where $\rho$ runs over all primes.  (I am not really too sure though, if that is really how I should define $\zeta(2)$.  Any way, I just based my definition off this [answer to a closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099121/28816).)

**Update (September 18, 2020 - 6:16 PM Manila time)** I was wrong, the correct formula for $\zeta(2)$ should have been
$$\zeta(2) = \prod_{\rho}{\dfrac{{\rho}^2}{(\rho - 1)(\rho + 1)}},$$
as correctly pointed out by [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967).

Note that we can write
$$m = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{{\rho_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
so that we have
$$m^2 = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{{\rho_i}^{2\alpha_i}}$$
and therefore
$$\sigma(m^2) = \sigma\Bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{{\rho_i}^{2\alpha_i}}\Bigg) = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{\sigma\bigg({\rho_i}^{2\alpha_i}\bigg)}$$
from which we get
$$I(m^2) = \dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{\sigma\bigg({\rho_i}^{2\alpha_i}\bigg)}}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{{\rho_i}^{2\alpha_i}}}.$$

*This is where I get stuck.  I currently do not see a way to force the inequality
$$I(m^2) > \prod_{\rho}{\bigg({\rho}^2 + {\rho} + 1\bigg)},$$
where $\rho$ runs over all primes, from everything that I have written so far.*

Comment: Since $\alpha_i \geq 1$ for each $i$, then
$$I(m^2) \geq \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{I\bigg({\rho_i}^2\bigg)}$$
which *seems closer* ("for lack of a better word") to
$$\displaystyle\prod_{\rho}{\Bigg({\rho}^2 + {\rho} + 1\Bigg)}.$$

Comment: It is wrong that $\zeta(2) = \displaystyle\prod_{\rho}{({\rho}^2 + {\rho} + 1)}$. Since we have $\zeta(s)=\displaystyle\prod_{\rho}(1-{\rho}^{-s})^{-1}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product)), we get $\zeta(2)=\displaystyle\prod_{\rho}\dfrac{{\rho}^2}{({\rho}-1)({\rho}+1)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your correction, @mathlove!  Notwithstanding, would it still be possible to prove the conjecture $I(m^2) > \zeta(2)$?

Comment: By the argument you give, this question is equivalent to asking whether it is possible that $p=5$ and $k\geq 5$. I do not believe this is known (e.g. there is no known way to rule out an odd perfect number of the form $5^5\cdot m^2$ for some $m$ with $5\nmid m$) so this inequality would not be provable without a significant new idea.

Comment: @ThomasBloom:  Actually, Cohen and Sorli ruled out $5^5$ as a possible Eulerian component $p^k$ for an odd perfect number in page 4 of their paper titled [On Odd Perfect Numbers and Even 3-Perfect Numbers](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a6self/a6self.pdf).  Does this mean that the proof for $I(m^2) > \zeta(2)$ is *indeed* within reach?  =)

Comment: Ah, yes. I doubt it, since one would have to rule out $5^k\cdot m^2$ (with $5\nmid m$) for all $k\geq 5$. I don't see how one would rule this out for absurdly large $k$.

Comment: Thus, under the assumption $q=5$ and $k>1$, we have that $k \geq 9$ (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), whereupon we obtain
$$I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)} \leq \frac{2}{I(5^9)} \leq \frac{1953125}{1220703} \approx 1.60000016384.$$
Hence, my interest in a lower bound for $I(m^2)$ that is obtained independently of Cohen and Sorli's results.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, if $x=p^km^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, so that $p\equiv k\equiv1\pmod{4}$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$, it follows that
$$I(m^2)=\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{m^2}=\frac{p^k}{\sigma(p^k)}\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k}\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{m^2}=\frac{p^k}{\sigma(p^k)}\frac{\sigma(p^km^2)}{p^km^2}=\frac{p^k}{\sigma(p^k)}I(x)=2\frac{p^k}{\sigma(p^k)},$$
where of course
$$\sigma(p^k)=\sum_{i=0}^kp^i=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1},$$
from which it follows that
$$I(m^2)=2\frac{p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}=2\frac{p-1}{p-\tfrac{1}{p^k}}.$$
The latter allows several simple lower bounds. For example
$$2\frac{p-1}{p-\tfrac{1}{p^k}}>2\frac{p-1}{p}=2\left(1-\frac1p\right)\geq\frac85,$$
because $p\geq5$. In particular, if $p\neq5$ we see that $p\geq13$ and so
$$I(m^2)>2\left(1-\frac1p\right)\geq2\left(1-\frac{1}{13}\right)=\frac{24}{13}>\zeta(2).$$
So it remains to show that the inequality holds if $p=5$. In this case we have
$$I(m^2)=2\frac{p-1}{p-\tfrac{1}{p^k}}=\frac{8}{5-\tfrac{1}{5^k}}.$$
This is a strictly decreasing function of $k$, and for $k=1,5$ we find that
$$I(m^2)=\frac{8}{5-\tfrac15}=\frac{5}{3}>\zeta(2),$$
$$I(m^2)=\frac{8}{5-\tfrac{1}{5^5}}=\frac{3125}{1953}<\zeta(2),$$
so your question is equivalent to asking whether there exists an odd perfect number $x$ of the form $x=5^km^2$ with $5\nmid m$ and $k\equiv1\pmod{4}$ and $k\geq5$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited on May 14, 2023 (22:50 PM - Manila time)**

Adding an answer to complement [Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30382/servaes)'s response - These are actually some minor thoughts that would be too long to fit in the *Comments* section.

In what follows, I will let $N = p^k m^2$ denote an odd perfect number with *special prime* $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

---

Consider the equation $I(m^2) = \zeta(2)$. This equation does not hold, since $LHS$ is rational while $RHS$ is transcendental.

Summarizing my takeaways from [Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30382/servaes)'s [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3831635/28816):

> - Servaes concluded (on **September 18, 2020 at 20:14 PM**) that we have the implication
>   $$\left((p = 5) \land (k \neq 1)\right) \implies I(m^2) < \zeta(2). \tag{1}$$
> - It remains to consider the inequality $I(m^2) < \zeta(2)$. Note that
>   $$\frac{2(p - 1)}{p} < I(m^2) < \zeta(2)$$
>   implies that
>   $$p < \frac{12}{12 - {\pi}^2} \approx 5.63275666,$$
>   from which we infer that $p=5$. Substituting $p=5$ into
>   $$I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)} = \frac{2p^k (p - 1)}{p^{k+1} - 1}$$
>   we get the inequality
>   $$I(m^2) = \frac{8\cdot{5^k}}{5^{k+1} - 1} < \zeta(2).$$
>   Solving for $k$, we finally obtain
>   $$k > \frac{2 \log{\pi} - \log(5{\pi}^2 - 48)}{\log 5} = 2\log_{5}(\pi)-\log_{5}(5{\pi}^2 - 48) \approx 1.23696690592779795755777497329666 > 1.$$
>   This means that we have the implication
>   $$I(m^2) < \zeta(2) \implies \left((p = 5) \land (k \neq 1)\right). \tag{2}$$

---

> - Therefore, we can conclude (from Implications **(1)** and **(2)**) that we have the biconditional
>   $$\left(I(m^2) < \zeta(2)\right) \iff \left((p = 5) \land (k \neq 1)\right).$$

---

<s>I will stop here for the time being, as I have to rest.</s>

Either way, note that
$$I(m^2) > \zeta(2) \text{     improves on   } I(m^2) > \frac{8}{5},$$
while
$$I(m^2) < \zeta(2) \text{     improves on   } I(m^2) < 2.$$

Comment: Thank you for the first downvote.  This is *much appreciated*!  (I *perfectly* understand.)  @wink@

Comment: My profuse thanks for the upvote!  =)